# Android: Dynamically adding images at right to dynamic table rows

Tags: android, tablelayout

I need to add the imageview at the right side of table row  that is generated dynamically..
I have added imageviews to table rows.. How to add images at right i.e. set gravity to right.
Can anyone help me over this?
Thanks

Comment: paste your xml code for custom adapter here

Comment: I am adding table rows to table layout dynamically and also imageviews to table layout dynamically

Comment: Have you tried iv.setGravity(Gravity.center); or something like that

Comment: No method like this fo r setting gravity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a XML file for table row and Using LayoutInflater you can get a view from that XML file.

You have to study about [Layout Inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Comment: But i need to add table layouts dynamically

Comment: I am telling you about the same.To add table rows in table layout,The best way is you create table row from xml using layout-inflater so that its works speedy and you do not have to dynamically set controls position in table row.